# How to pass csrf token to an upload component from antd?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, csrf, antd

In a form when passing csrf tokens I use a hidden input to pass the value a long.

```
<Form method="post" action="/account/user" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  <Input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value={this.state.session.csrfToken} onChange={()=>{}}/>
  <FormGroup row>
    <Label sm={2}>Name:</Label>
    <Col sm={10} md={8}>
      <Input name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
    </Col>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

How do you do that when you have a component like this? It's the upload component from antd.

```
render() {
  const props = {
    name: 'file',
    action: '//localhost/file/upload',
    onChange(info) {

    }
  };

  return (
    <Dragger {...props}>
      // drag and drop area
    </Dragger>
  )
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `data` property.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it ended up being a headers prop.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being a prop that was available called headers that I could include. Hope that helps someone else along the way.

```
render() {
            const props = {
                name: 'file',
                action: '//localhost/file/upload',
                headers: {
                   'X-CSRF-Token': 'somelongtokenstring'
                }
                onChange(info) {

                }
            };

            return (
                   <Dragger {...props}>
                       // drag and drop area
                   </Dragger>
    )
    }
```

Comment: With `X-CSRF-Token` doesn't work, it needs to be `X-CSRFToken`. Sorry for the downvote but this drove us crazy for a while, so I wish for other readers to be aware :)